# Cakephp, change query to fetch all in one

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have multiple query in `foreach` i know its wrong and i want to correct it i have `virtual_fields` like this:

```
'night_hours' => 'SUM(Hour.night)',
'half_hours' => 'SUM(Hour.half)',
'NN' => 'SUM(Hour.day_off_id = 13)'
```

my `foreach` loop in controller:

```
foreach ($users as $user){
        $set_of_days = $this->Hour->find('all', array(
                'fields' => array('hour_from', 'hour_to', 'day_off_id', 'night_hours', 'half_hours', 'NN'),
                'conditions' => 
                    array('subordinate_id' => $user['User']['id'],
                          'date(Hour.date) BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($date_from, $date_to))));
```

its working fine but when i'll have 4k users in one view it will kill db, i wanted to join with table `users` with `hours` but i get error that column `night_hours` don't exist, do you guys know any way around?

Here is one of queries :

```
SELECT `Hour`.`hour_from`, `Hour`.`hour_to`, `Hour`.`day_off_id`, (SUM(`Hour`.`night`)) AS `Hour__night_hours`, (SUM(`Hour`.`half`)) AS `Hour__half_hours`, (SUM(`Hour`.`day_off_id` = 13)) AS `Hour__NN` FROM `kadry`.`hours` AS `Hour` WHERE `subordinate_id` = 193 AND date(`Hour`.`date`) BETWEEN '2014-01-11' AND '2014-02-11'
```

Comment: please post the code that doesn't work. Also, did you tried containable?

Comment: You mean something like `hasMany` etc ?

Comment: you mentioned you tried an unique query with joins but you got errors. Post that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have thiese columns `'night_hours', 'half_hours'` , in your query you gave it different alias

try this

```
  'fields' => array('hour_from', 'hour_to', 'day_off_id', 'Hour__night_hours', 'Hour__half_hours', 'NN'),
```

you ave aliases like that in your query

```
 SELECT `Hour`.`hour_from`,
          `Hour`.`hour_to`, 
          `Hour`.`day_off_id`,
          (SUM(`Hour`.`night`)) AS `Hour__night_hours`,   
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^//---> here your alias
          (SUM(`Hour`.`half`)) AS `Hour__half_hours`,   
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   //---> here your alias
          ......
          ......
```